# How to modify a scope's value within a directive

Tags: angularjs

Within a directive, I'd like to modify the expression's value when a button is clicked.  The below code is only modifying the value locally within my directive.  I'd like to change the value outside of this directive as well.  How can I accomplish that?

```
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            //toggle the state when clicked
            el.bind('click', function () {
                scope[attrs.ngModel] = !scope[attrs.ngModel];
            });
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xqYBnz5BHLP844kXJXKs?p=preview

Comment: You mean something like `scope.$apply`, specifically, `scope.$apply(function() { scope[attrs.ngModel] = !scope[attrs.ngModel]; });`

Comment: Can you check what `attrs.ngModel` gives, i think this returns the value of the attribute not name.

Comment: Can you please post a jsFiddle or Plunker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems is with the binding expression in ng-model. Since it has '.' in it, you need to use the `$parse` to get and set value correctly. See some documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse)

Something like

```
 var getter=$parse(attrs.ngModel);
 var setter=getter.assign;
 setter(scope,!getter(scope));
```

See my updated plunkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/VAE43y5cagCF8jq5AlaY?p=preview

Basically setting

```
scope[attrs.ngModel] = !scope[attrs.ngModel]
```

creates a new property `user.active`. To set it should be `scope['user']['active'];`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not creating a new scope, then you should be able to access the model via `scope` not `attrs`

In the directive, change the scope to

```
scope: {
    ngModel: '='
},
```

And change the scope.$apply to

```
scope.$apply(function () {
    if (scope.ngModel) {
        off();
        scope.ngModel = false;
    } else {
        on();
        scope.ngModel = true;
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/wH44YQFLX1TQJwwLcSn3?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: The scope path is an expression, thus can't be hard coded like `user.active` is in the above example.  I've tried doing `scope[expression]` and it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: @Webnet then you should pass it via a name defined in the directive

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way would be to create an isolate scope and pass in your directive an attribute that will link it to a method in the parent scope which will do the work of flipping the state.

Rough example:

In your directive definition:

```
scope: {
    flipState: '&'
},
link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
    elem.bind('click', function () {
        flipState();
    }
}
```

In your view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    /* ... */
    <button directivename flip-state="flipStateFunc()"></button>
</div>
```

And in your controller `MyController`:

```
flipStateFunc: function () {
    $scope.state = !$scope.state;
}
```

Comment: Not a bad thought, but I'm really hoping to avoid having to do that.

Comment: I don't see why avoid doing it this way. On the contrary, to make the directive reusable, it's better to have the work that corresponds to its callback be done by whoever uses the directive i.e. the enclosing scope, since it's the state of something in the enclosing scope that is affected.