# Dynamic NgModel Names

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm writing a directive that is re-used across a system that fetches postcodes.

```
//postcode grabber
app.directive('postcodes',
    function ($rootScope, $http) {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('change', function () {
                var modal_element = angular.element('#myModal');
                var ctrl = modal_element.controller();
                var url = '/postage/postcodes/?suburb=' + element.val() + "&target_suburb=" + attrs.targetSuburb + "&target_state=" + attrs.targetState + "&target_postcode=" + attrs.targetPostcode;
                ctrl.setModal(url);
                modal_element.modal('show');
            });
        };
    });
```

It opens up a bootstrap modal window on change which has a controller:

```
function PostcodesCtrl($scope, $parse) {
    $scope.populate = function (suburb, state, postcode, target_suburb, target_state, target_postcode) {
        //lets grab the controller of the target postcode
        var tpscope = angular.element(target_postcode).scope();
    }
}
PostcodesCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope'];
```

I got as far as accessing the scope of the target input fields (the tpscope line) using the input elements "ID" (eg.#suburb), but I am unsure how to update the ngModel values since they will always be different names.

This is why I'm sending the target_suburb, target_postcode etc to the server which then has an ng-click that returns them back to the "populate" function.

Is it possible to access scope variables dynamically? Like $scope[whatever].. or similar?

**Update:** I figured out I can access $scope[var] no probs, but ng-model names will have a decimal point... eg "model.suburb" - it seems to not like that.

If anyone has a better idea on how to do this, please let me know!

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446211/how-to-modify-a-scopes-value-within-a-directive/18447690#18447690

Comment: you're a legend!, add an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ngModel value with `.` requires special treatment to parse in directive and use it. You need to use the `$parse` service to handle the model in a the context of a scope. Something like

```
 var getter=$parse(attrs.ngModel);
 var setter=getter.assign;
 setter(scope,!getter(scope));
```